# Codeigniter: How to pass input values from one function to another function inside a controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new in codeigniter and I've already seen some similar types of questions here. But none worked in my case.
I've a form in my view and I've passed the input value from this form to a method named "Insert" inside the controller. Now,I'm trying to move this value from "insert" method "to another method named "post_action". But couldn't make it possible.

This is the Controller:

```
public function insert() {
        $data['values'] = $this->Final_model->insert();
        $this->load->view('info/insert',$data);


        $val = $this->input->post('coursecode'); 

        echo $val;


    $this->post_action($val); //passing data into another function

    }


public function post_action($val='')
    {   
        $temp1 = $this->input->post('textbox');
    if($temp1== "")
    {
        $message = "You can't send empty text";

    }
    else
    {
        print_r($val);

        if($val == NULL) echo 'Value is null bro...';


        $grades = $_POST['grade'];
        $msg = $_POST['my'];

        $message = $_POST['textbox'];
        $this->Final_model->build_post($msg,$val,$message,$grades);
        echo "Value added successfully";
        }

    }
```

This is my 'index' view :

```
<?php echo form_open('Home_Controller/insert'); ?>
 <div class="form-group">
<label>Course Code</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name = "coursecode"
placeholder="Add Course Code">
<br> <br>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This is my 'insert' view :

```
  <?php echo form_open('Home_controller/post_action'); ?>
<td> <input type="text" name="textbox" id = "textbox"> </td>
<td><input type="text" name="grade" id = "grade1"></td>
<input type="hidden" name = "my" value = "<?php  echo $value['id']; ?>" 
id 
= "my"/>
<td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
</form>
```

Now, it is echoing the correct value in the insert method passed by the view. But in the post_action method, it is echoing "value is null bro" and a 0 is passing to the database table(this one is an insert operation done in the model).

My question is,why can't I get the input value  passed from the view, in this post_action method.

P.S: I've already spent about 2 days in this problem but haven't got anything. So, please forgive me if the question is too naive. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Please try with this Controller:

```
<?php


public function insert()
{

    $data['values'] = $this->Final_model->insert();
    $this->load->view('info/insert',$data);

    $val['coursecode'] = $this->input->post('coursecode');
    echo $val['coursecode']; //echoing value from post

    if(!empty($val)){
        $this->post_action($val); //passing val into another function
    } else {
        echo "Didn't get value from post";
    }

}

public function post_action($val = '')
{
    if(is_array($val) && count($val) > 0)
    {
        $grades = $_POST['grade'];
        $msg = $_POST['my'];

        $message = $_POST['textbox'];
        $this->Final_model->build_post($msg,$val,$message,$grades);
        echo "Value added successfully";
    } 
    else 
    {
       echo "No result found";
    }
}


?>
```

Comment: In the insert function, it is echoing the passed input value. But in the post_action function, it is echoing "No result found".